# Ensure binding for $watch when $firebaseArray or $firebaseObject returns empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using Angularfire and there is a situation when `$firebaseArray` or `$firebaseObject` return nothing at first. It's because it's empty or not existed yet. But I want to do $watch for that object/array all the times. Let say later on, the node actually exists. The original `$firebaseArray` or `$firebaseObject` does not trigger $watch event.

How do I ensure binding for $watch to happen even when the node is empty / not exist at first? This happens when I create a new user and there is nothing in a certain node.

**UPDATE 1**

http://plnkr.co/edit/tQur74nkRIE9ZOiJUAgf?p=preview

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['firebase']);
var Ref = new Firebase('https://so32556276.firebaseio.com');

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  $scope.data = $firebaseObject(Ref.child('user'));

  $scope.data.$loaded().then(function(res) {
    $scope.data.$watch(function(e) {
      console.log('Something changed');
      console.log(e);
    });
  });

  $scope.changeName = function() {
    $scope.data.name = "test2";
    $scope.data.$save();
  }

  $scope.changeAge = function() {
    $scope.data.age = "10";
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{data.name}}!</p>
    <p>Your age is {{data.age}}!</p>
    <a href="" ng-click="changeName()">Change Name</a><br>
    <a href="" ng-click="changeAge()">Change Age</a>
  </body>
```

**Firebase**

[image]

If I click "Change Name", you can see the log event here:

```
Something changed
app.js:10 Object {event: "value", key: "user"}
```

If I click "Change Age", although the frontend can detect the variable, `$watch` has no visibility into this. Nothing out in console.

Any clue how to avoid this?

Comment: I updated with code above.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the plunkr. With those it was very easy to figure out what's going wrong. Answer below. Cleaning up comments above.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases where I see people trying to use `$loaded()`, they are still stuck in a "first load the data and then do..." mindset. Firebase (and thus AngularFire) are a "synchronize this data and whenever it changes do..." system. Your use of `$watch()` is definitely the right approach, you just attached it at the wrong moment.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  $scope.data = $firebaseObject(Ref.child('user'));

  $scope.data.$loaded().then(function(res) {
    $scope.data.$watch(function(e) {
      console.log('Something changed');
      console.log(e);
    });
  });
```

The `$loaded()` promise is fulfilled once the initial data has loaded from Firebase; or one Firebase has determined that there is no data yet. You only register the `$watch()` handler *after* the initial data has loaded, so it will only fire for changes after that.

The solution is to immediately attach the `$watch()` handler to the `$firebaseObject`:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  $scope.data = $firebaseObject(Ref.child('user'));
  $scope.data.$watch(function(e) {
    console.log('Something changed');
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

To me it sounds like you just want to extend the service and listen to the `$$added` and `$$updated` event.

Here is an example on how to extend.

```
var userFactory = $firebaseArray.$extend({    
    //This is called anytime a new user_node is added   
    $$added: function(dataSnapshot){
        var user = dataSnapshot.val(); //This is the data
        var user_key = dataSnapshot.key(); //The users id
        user.$id = user_key;  
        //This user.$id is important if you want to 
        //make modifications to the user 


        //Perhaps add new properties to your user
        return user; 
    },
    $$updated: function(dataSnapshot){
       //An update has been made
       var changed = false; 
       //Go through your data, if changed change the variable. 
       return changed;
    }
});

//Instantiate
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("your_ref");
var firebaseUserConnection = new userFactory(firebaseRef);
```

You may also listen to other events such as `$$removed` and many more, have a look at [Extending the service](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html)